# How to collect multiple btsnoop log files in Bluedroid

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm running Bluetooth Stability test, it runs for 24 hours. For this long time when I see the Bluedroid BTSnoop logs, the logs are so big in size, ~5GB. Problem is I can't open this much big log in Frontline Capture File Viewer.
I want a way so that I can collect BTSnoop logs in small size files, so that every file could be viewed easily.
Please suggest.

Comment: Any suggestions on this please!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to open the file in Wireshark, and cut it to smaller chunks which are digestible for frontline.